# Не могу работать с Git в IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea, github

Всем добрый день!

У меня в IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.3 внезапно снизу справа пропала надпись Git, остался только значок двух треугольников:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я пробовал закоммитить изменения, но после нажатия кнопки "Commit..." ничего не произошло. Связь с Git и с GitHub есть, протестил в настройках. В "VCS -> Git" не работают кнопки с "Branches..." до "Reset HEAD...", просто ноль реакции.  Пробовал создать новый проект, в нем после отправки коммита высвечивается надпись, что никаких изменений в проекте нет.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

**UPDATE:** Я обнаружил еще один непонятный момент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Local Changes в любом из моих проектов теперь горит надпись "updating...", что он апдейтит я не понимаю.

Comment: в папке проекта есть .git ?

Comment: Да, такая папка присутствует

Comment: Покажите вывод `ls -l .git/*` (или аналогичную, если это виндовс).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данная проблема решилась очень просто - переустановкой Идеи. Теперь Git в Идее работает корректно.

Answer (score 2):

Зайдите в меню VCS -> Enable Version Control Integration

Выберите Git и нажмите OK. Существующая папка .git должна подцепиться, либо будет создана новая, если её нет.

[image: Demonstration of Enable Version Control Integration window]

Comment: Если и это не сработает, можно обновить или переустановить плагин Git integration. Плагины иногда ломаются при обновлении самой IDE, что может приводить к подобному результату.

Comment: В Enable Version Control Integration не могу зайти, этот раздел горит темно-серым. Плагин тоже удалить не получается, конкретно в нем нет пункта "Uninstall". Также я обнаружил еще одну проблему, см. в вопросе пункт "UPDATE" .

Comment: а в settings меню version control доступно?

Comment: Да, раздел Version Control доступен

Comment: там есть ваш Git репозиторий?

Comment: В пункте Directory указана директория репозитория, в пункте VCS указан Git

Comment: Попробуйте удалить оттуда и добавить по новой

Comment: Тоже не помогло. Скорее всего это Идея шалит после обновления, потому что даже после клонирования проекта и создания нового у меня эта проблема не исчезает